# when tring to update or install new packages i alwaus get this error

Tags: laravel, composer-php

curl error 28 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Connection timed out after 10002 milliseconds

composer update  or install packages

when I search about it related to  a firewall or security modules, not a networking connection issue

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue. What did you try to resolve it?

Comment: when I search about it related to  a firewall or security modules, not a networking connection issue

Comment: Yes it's a network timeout. What is your question? @TarekHassan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more thing to check is your ip addressing. I sometimes had this issue when my home network was assigning me ipv6 address instead of ipv4.